# Program crashes when allocating memory for object array

Tags: c++

My code is something like this in C++

```
MyObject* someObject;

void makeArray(int sizeArray)
{
    someObject = (MyObject*) malloc(sizeof(MyObject) * sizeArray);
}
```

Now this compiles without any errors or warnings, but when I run the program it instantly crashes. I have also tried to hardcode the array in, and I do have enough memory for it.  I haven't used malloc too much, so I probably have something coded wrong, but if that's the problem, what is it?

Comment: don't use `malloc` in C++ unless you're overloading operator `new`

Comment: use neither `malloc` nor `new` in C++

Comment: @rightfold - Eh? Not using `new` in C++?

Comment: @EdHeal Eh, yes? See [_C++11 Style_](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style).

Comment: (There are exceptions, of course. For example, when dealing with a crappy API or when implementing the C++ standard library.)

Answer (score 3):

#### Memory allocation is not construction

You should not use `malloc` when you are creating objects that have a non-trivial constructor, mainly because `malloc` will **not** call any constructor; it will merely allocate memory, nothing more.

In *C++*, you use *operator new* to allocate memory **and** construct the object:

```
MyObject* someObject;

void makeArray(int sizeArray) {
    someObject = new MyObject[sizeArray];
}
```

<sup>**Note**: For every *new* you shall have a matching *delete*, please remember to use `delete[] someObject` when you are done.</sup>

---

#### Recommended solutions

The *C++ way* of doing things is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which will handle memory management, and object construction/destruction for you:

```
std::vector<MyObject> vec (sizeArray); // create a vector with `sizeArray` elements
```

If you *"must"* use pointers please don't use *raw-pointers*, instead you should use smart-pointers if those are available under your implementation:

- **[What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/1090079)**

Comment: In was in earlier versions of C++

Comment: I would argue that the right solution is to use `std::vector<MyObject>` in C++Anything. As for Ed's comment, the point is that you make it sound as if you couldn't dynamically allocate an array with `new` before C++11. (not my down-vote BTW)

Comment: - `new` was in the earlier versions of C++

Comment: @juanchopanza - It depends. Sometimes using new is useful when performing custom memory allocations

Comment: @EdHeal opsie, weird typo: **fixed**!

Comment: @juanchopanza added wording regarding `std::vector`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `malloc` in C++? `new` is what you should be using

i.e.

```
someObject = new MyObject[sizeArray];
```

then use `delete[]` to delete it!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but think the better recommendation is to use a `std::vector<>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - It is an answer to the question and is correct. Seems rather harsh to downvote but I will bear it in mind.

Comment: I told you I didn't downvote! I just put a comment with some criticism.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I took your comment to mean that the person that downvoted was due to me not mentioning vector